# why this partial not working

Tags: clojure, partial

Here is my code:

```
(def partial-join (partial (clojure.string/join ",")))

=>(clojure.string/join "," ["foo" "bar"])
"foo,bar"

=> (partial-join ["foo" "bar"])
```

And it raises this exception:

> ClassCastException java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  .repl/eval12557 (form-init2162333644921704923.clj:1)

Comment: You are adding an extra layer of parenthesis that should not be there when using partial.

Answer (score 2):

See the doc of `clojure.string/join`.

```
clojure.string/join
([coll] [separator coll])
  Returns a string of all elements in coll, as returned by (seq coll),
   separated by an optional separator.
```

when only one argument is provided for `clojure.string/join`, this function regard its argument as collection, so:

```
user=> (clojure.string/join ",")
","
```

Next, see the doc of `partial`.

```
clojure.core/partial
([f] [f arg1] [f arg1 arg2] [f arg1 arg2 arg3] [f arg1 arg2 arg3 & more])
  Takes a function f and fewer than the normal arguments to f, and
  returns a fn that takes a variable number of additional args. When
  called, the returned function calls f with args + additional args.
```

When only one argument provided, `partial` returns its argument.

```
user=> (partial (clojure.string/join ",")) 
","
```

Try this:

```
user=> (def partial-join (partial clojure.string/join ","))
#'user/partial-join
user=> (partial-join ["a" "b"])
"a,b"
```

Comment: agatain is correct, but keep in mind `#(clojure.string/join "," %)` works too.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is NOT with the number of parameters passed to clojure.string/join. The problem is the brackets surrounding clojure.string/join call the function and the result of the function call is passed to partial. What you want to do is pass the function and the first param to partial as below:

```
(def partial-join (partial clojure.string/join ","))
(partial-join ["foo" "bar"])
;; => "foo,bar"
```

Comment: (partial clojure.string/join ",")
  ;; => #function[clojure.core/partial/fn--5908]